# Classification of Sasaki manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is there a classification of Sasaki or Sasaki-Einstein manifolds?
What are important examples?

Comment: "important" is one of those words which is probably observer-dependent.  So what do you have in mind by an important example?  i.e., important for what?  I could perhaps add some more to my answer in order to address that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book [Sasakian Geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=ERYZAQAAIAAJ) by Charles Boyer and the late Krzysztof Galicki contains a wealth of information on this topic.  As far as I know there is no classification, but there are of course tons of examples.

Comment: I am for example interessting what is the Reeb vectorfield $\xi$ and the Sasaki structure $\Phi$ in special examples, may be in $M=S^{2m+1}$ or $M=\mathbb{R}^{2m+1}$.
Can you say this? 

Thank you and best regards 